# React Router useLocation hook won't return the full URL when there is a # present in the URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The way my routing is setup, the URL might be something like

```
localhost:3000/alpha/beta/gamma#4
```

When I use the location hook from react-router like follows:

```
let loc = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loc.pathname)
})
```

It will console log:

```
alpha/beta/gamma
```

and cut off the #4. How can I avoid this from happening and return the full URL?

Comment: A url has different components, such as the path, query and fragment. You asked for the path, and # marks the start of the 'fragment' part of url, so its not part of the path.

Comment: Fair enough, is there a way to ask for the entire URL without splitting it into a pathname and hash separately?

Comment: The full URL would include the domain and scheme, which sounds like is also not what you want. So maybe just get 2 components you want (or 3 if you also want the query) and concatenate them back together?

Comment: DrZoo's [answer](/a/73328206/8690857) provided below *should* answer your question and return pathname + hash, i.e. `"/alpha/beta/gamma#4"`. Have you tried that solution out? What is the issue, if any, that remains?

Comment: Yeah both answers are imho good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useLocation() creates a location object property which contains the following:

- hash
- pathname
- search
- state
- key

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1) the query string (search) should come before the fragment (hash).

If you want to get a full URL, you should get the pathname with `loc.pathname`. Then check for query params aka search with `loc.search`, then fragments aka hash with `loc.hash` and concatenate them together.

Answer (score 1):

you need to read the [hash #] and [search] values from useLocation hook, try this :

```
import useLocation from "react-router-dom";
```

then inside your app

```
const { hash, search } = useLocation();
```

more about [useLocation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/uselocation)